# No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'. Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I am creating form validation in angular and I am getting error

> No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'.

My code:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" 
                     appForbiddenName="bob" ngModel #name="ngModel">
                     
      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf>First name required</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment</label>
      <textarea name="" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[image: image of editor]

The error:

```
     Error: src/app/app.component.html:6:60 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'.
    
    6                      appForbiddenName="bob" ngModel #name="ngModel">
                                                                 ~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
        5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you work with angular template-driven forms and want to use #name="ngModel" you also need to use `[(ngModel)]="mymodel"` directive in the same input, and of course,

```
Add import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

to your `app.module.ts` and in the import array you need to add FormsModule.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get such error make sure you have imported the `forms module` in the main module.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <== add the imports!
 
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,                               
    ReactiveFormsModule                       
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
    // other components here
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648407/angular2-error-there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngform) for more details.

Comment: If that helps you can accept and upvote it. We both will be rewarded for that thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was migrating an Angular 8 application over to an Angular 13 UI Kit that I purchased. I ran into this issue. I was getting the exportAs 'ngModel' and 'ngForm' error. It turns out that I missed adding one of my Tab pages to the app-module. I spent hours trying to figure this out. Had nothing to do with adding the FormsModule.

Comment: Correct. I have mentioned a similar solution here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106910/angular-there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngmodel/75831106#75831106