# Upgradation of Nebular Theme(4.4.0 to 9.0.1) wrt Angular (8.2.3 to 13.2.1)

Tags: angular, nebular

While Upgradation of Nebular Theme(4.4.0 to 9.0.1) wrt Angular (8.2.3 to 13.2.1) I am facing following issues:

1. 'nb-card-header' is not a known element:

- If 'nb-card-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
- If 'nb-card-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2. No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'.

```
[(ngModel)]="startupWizard.company.state" #state="ngModel">
```

3. Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a
   known property of 'input'.

```
[(ngModel)]="startupWizard.company.state" #state="ngModel">
```

I would like to know the best possible option to upgrade Nebular to Angular version 13?.

Does latest version of Nebular 9.1 support angular 13?.If yes, how can we migrate the old components to the latest one

Answer (score 0):

I've recently managed to migrate to Angular 13 and Nebular 9, so it is possible (thought I needed to replace or delete some dependencies, but ngx-admin is working as intended).

I've used [this site](https://update.angular.io) to properly migrate to Angular 13.

So, to the questions:

> 1. 'nb-card-header' is not a known element

This error appears because something that is using `nb-card-header` can't find it in the used modules. To fix this issue, you need to add `NbCardModule` to the `imports` array of your Module in the`.module.ts` file (the module that uses the template that tries to use `nb-card-header`).

Speaking of the last two issues, the may be related. For the second issue try finding other questions that mention `No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'.`, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106910/angular-there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngmodel). Or probably [in the documentation about ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel). You can also try adding `FormsModule` to the imports of your Module.